# XLForm Cell numberOfLines

Tags: ios, xlform

Any pros out there using XLForm and have any idea on how to configure the cell such that the `textLabel.numberOfLines` can be changed to 2? I have a very long string that cannot fit in 1 line.

Any suggestions or thoughts is really appreciated! Thank you very much in advance!!! =D

Comment: u change `textLabel.numberOfLines=0;` and try.

Comment: @Ilesh You inspired me to try putting "0", and I saw some changes. So I played with the number until I got what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this did the trick:

```
[self.row.cellConfigAtConfigure setObject:@(3) forKey:@"textLabel.numberOfLines"];
```

Comment: Works for me, but for a 3 line text, the text is draw outside of the cell, over the other cells.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me:

```
form +++= TextRow() {
            $0.cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
            $0.title = "Some long string that doesn't fit iPhone 5 screen width"
            $0.placeholder = "Provide your answer"
        }
```